# How to parse Wikihow with this API?

Tags: php, api

I want to be able to parse the website wikihow.com, so after some reasearch I find this [page](http://www.wikihow.com/api.php). But despites my reading I don't know who to parse the website.

For example, when I make a [search](http://www.wikihow.com/Special:LSearch?search=frie) on the website, I have a list of links with images to choose which I want to read.

So I try to do the same with the api. I try to use the query option like this : `http://www.wikihow.com/api.php?action=query&titles=fries`. Nothing came. Is it really an API for the website. Do you have an example of how to use the api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, wikiHow's API is the same as MediaWiki's API..But it does not provide API like http://www.wikihow.com/api.php?action=query&titles=fries

Comment: So, my question is, Is there any solution to parse the content of the search  ? I succeed to do so with curl, but if the html change, I'm damn :/. Is there any elegant solution ?

Comment: DOM (http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) is also available insted of CURL..but if HTML is changed then we can't do anything..
If you want some brief about keyword (ex here is fries). You can also use this :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch=apple&srwhat=nearmatch